# How does Rails' form_for work with nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused form the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) about using a form for creating each comment. From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), I get that you usually pass the model object name as the first parameter to `form_for`, but how does `@article.comments.build` here work? How does Rails know to build a for a form for each comment that would belong to article? The docs don't explain a signature that matches the below-

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: If you take a look at the Article model, you can see that there is a `has_many :comments` line on it. If there is a column in `article_id` in comment table, @article.comments can easily map the comments of that particular article(searching by article_id).

Dont know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From [Getting Started with Rails Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller):

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

> This adds a form on the Article show page that creates a new comment by calling the CommentsController create action. The form_for call here uses an array, which will build a nested route, such as /articles/1/comments.

So, it is using an array as the first argument in `form_for` and the above section explained it as well that it will build a nested route like this `/articles/1/comments` to tell your `CommentsController` on which article this comment should be created.

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete role if of `routes` and `controller`. Lets see from the starting:

Your route says:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

So to create `comments` your route will be like: `/articles/1/comments` so this denotes that the `comment` is for `Article` with `id: 1`.

Now in your controller your `create` action is like this:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

So here you can see we are finding the `@article` using the `params[:article_id]` which comes from the `url`. So this will return 1 and `@article` will have the object of `Article` with `id: 1`. And then in the next line you are creating the `@comment` like this:

```
@comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
```

So this will create `Comment` which will belong to `Article` with `id: 1`.

Now talking about the `form_for` and the doubt you have:

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

This does nothing it will just create the `form` which will submit to the desired url which is `article/:id/comments` with a `POST` request. So as you are hitting on this route it identifies that you need to create this `Comment` for an `Article`.

If suppose you have a route like this:

```
resources :comments
```

Then to `create` the `Comment` you will be hitting the route `/comments` which will never know it belongs to an `Article` until you send an `article_id` explicitly.